# Angular 5, adding new row in array and save that

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, angular5

I have array like this:

```
dataTest = [{name: 'Foo'},{name: 'Bar'}]
```

I'm showing all data throught matIntput. On my click I'm adding new row in array and showing empty input. That is all oke, but when I change my data to that new row with null to something like John for example and I click save, there is no changes in my array and it's look something like this:

```
dataTest = [{name: 'Foo'},{name: 'Bar'},{name: null}]
```

This is my app.compoent.html:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div class="flex wrap vertical-align" *ngFor="let profile of dataTest; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field class="profile-name name">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" value="{{profile.name}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="action-group">
        <span class="add-button"(click)="add()">ADD</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button class="background-white" mat-button mat-dialog-close>CANCEL</button>
  <button class="background-primary" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" cdkFocusInitial (click)="save(dataTest)">SAVE</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

This is my app.compoent.ts:

```
private add(): void {
 const rules: any = {
    name: ''
 };
 this.dataTest.push(rules);
 console.log(this.dataTest);
};


private save(dataTest) {
 console.log(dataTest)
}
```

Any help or idea what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: there is no two-way binding at all.

Comment: try console.log(this.dataTest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ngModel like below:-

```
<input matInput placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="profile.name">
```

Don't forget to import FormsModule, if you haven't already.